# /1 was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I'm having trouble with this prank `batch file script` I wrote, and whenever i open it after the press any key to continue I get the `"/1 was unexpected at this time"` error and i don't know how to fix it, I'm also not the greatest at scripting to please make it understandable. The script is below. Problem is coming from the `"/1 %%A in (100, -1, 0) do ("` part.

Also Here is the image of the script !
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eie8e.jpg]

Comment: `FOR /1` doesn't exist? Use `FOR /L` if you want to use a counter with a `FOR` loop.

Comment: We don't debug images of code or script, we don't debug code that isn't posted here in your question, and we don't answer questions that show such little effort. You'll need to [edit] your question, provide a better explanation of the problem, and include the code here if you want us to help you.

Comment: @Laf: Please don't answer questions like this in the comments. Doing so removes all incentive for the user to improve it, and leaves the cruft behind with no value for future readers. Comment asking them to improve it, or vote to close it, instead.

Comment: @KenWhite True, I should have done so, will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `FOR /1` use `FOR /L`. Why do you need this script... It doesn't do anything.